# Turkish 24 hours transit Visa for Bangladesh Holder

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, turkey, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi citizen with an air ticket from Jeddah to Dhaka via Istanbul. I want to spend some time outside of Istanbul Airport. How can I get a Turkish 24-hour transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

**If, and only if**, you have a visa or residence permit from a Schengen state, the UK, the US or Ireland, you can get an e-visa through this website https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/

Otherwise, you'd Need to apply for a transit visa at a Turkish embassy.

There is no special 24-hour transit visa I'm afraid, so these are your options

Comment: He must also be traveling "for purpose of tourism or business", i.e. not employment.

Comment: Kiosks are gone now. Website is the only available option.

Comment: @HankyPanky There are still visa-on-arrival desks (some sources claim there aren't anymore, but I've seen there are), though Bangladeshis are not eligible for that

Comment: Yes but those don’t offer eVisas. I meant to say website is the only option for eVisas.